# How works notifications on windows (registry, no shortlink)

Tags: windows, notifications, registry

I've a background application for my company, and i wants to show some notifications. This application is started with user session, so i don't wants to create a shortlink into startup menu. Can i do it?

---

Rethoric question because there is 0 documentation by microsoft on how do it.

Answer (score 2):

We will consider that the application have the next appId : "try-notifications"
First : You must create a registry key here to enable notifications :

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications\Backup\try-notifications]
"appType"="app:desktop"
"Setting"="s:banner,s:toast,s:audio,c:toast,c:ringing"
"wnsId"="NonImmersivePackage"
```

Second : You must create the second registry key to create some notification without create a shortlink into startup menu (like snoretoast do) :

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppUserModelId\try-notifications]
"CustomActivator"="{4742f671-9672-4857-9d6e-5857964f6b66}"
"DisplayName"="My application"
```

Explanations:

- The 'main' key will create an application for windows
- The 'DisplayName' will attach a name to show it in the notification (only if you give an icon on the notification) and set the name of notification group in notification center
- The 'CustomActivator' will store the notification in notification center if user not click on the notification. Without this key the notification will completly disappear if user not click on it.

And it's magic : You don't have to reference this GUID into CLSID, windows is ok with it.... hum...

I hope helpped someone today :)